# Interface programming

Tags: .net, interface, dependency-injection, class-design

**Background**

A developer on my team has implemented an application which I was reviewing. He has used interfaces everywhere. The app has typical service layer, data layer and POCO objects passed from website down to DB.

---

**Assumption**

IOC used (through Unity) to inject a runtime concrete Service and Data class.
All POCOs have nothing but get and set methods on public properties.

---

**Question**

I understand why an interface is used at the Service and Data layer but why would you use interfaces on all POCO objects? Is this overkill?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ may suit better for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the POCO interfaces serve a purpose? If yes, they may not be overkill. However, if they are not used, they violate the [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it) principle.

However, on a more general note, I'm beginning to think that **properties on interfaces are design smells**, as they violate the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_Of_Demeter).

I recently posted [some thoughts on better abstractions](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/12/03/TowardsBetterAbstractions.aspx).

Comment: I would disagree. Unless the interface has 100 properties, the properties should be relevant to the contract. Of course I disagree with your statement as a generalized overview but certainly we've both seen smelly interfaces...

Comment: Read your blog post. Most interesting.

Comment: Interfaces are not contracts: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/12/02/InterfacesAreNotAbstractions.aspx.

Comment: Another great read, but I still believe that an interface is a contract. It's a garuntee that an instance of an class that implements the interface is in fact going to expose the members defined in the interface. How a dev might implement the ReadFile() by pulling from a database and thus causing SqlExceptions is another discussion. Interface by no means garuntees correct functionality. Hmm, the more I go over it the more i'm seeing your point.

Comment: An interface is NOT a _full_ contract, because it doesn't define the _semantics_ of its members, only their _syntax_. You can use real Design by Contract to achieve that. In .NET, look at Code Contracts.

Comment: Not sure I agree with the properties sentiment, since properties are just syntactic sugar for methods anyway.

Comment: @Rex M: Yes, but it's about what properties *imply*. I would maintain the same argument against property methods in Java.

Comment: @Mark-Seemann - your blogs are interesting and a good read. The developer's intentions were loose coupling. The Employee class implements the IEmployee interface and whenever an Employee is passed around its the interface - but why bother? For classes that don't implement any behaviour I felt this was overkill. His argument is that you could swap out the concrete implementation of Employee. I can't think of a reason why for POCO objects.

Comment: @Alan Alcock: In general I tend to agree with you. Loose coupling should mostly be about decoupling *behavior*. However, in the blog post linked in my answer I talk about *Composable return types*. In such scenarios, if you have a service with behavior that returns a POCO instance, it would be better to return an interface. However, it would be better still to refactor the interfaces to avoid such situations entirely.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your POCOs are used simply as [Data Transfer Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object). If that's the case, they're just carrying information, with no behavior. Creating interfaces for them is overkill.